# How do logicians notate a proposition that posits the instantiation of a property?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

In The Oxford Companion to Philosophy, the entry on existence includes this paragraph.

> It is often held that ‘exist’ is not a firstlevel
>   predicate. What this means is that ‘exist’ does not
>   express a property of objects, as verbs like ‘shine’ and ‘fall’
>   do. According to Frege and Russell, ‘exist’ is a second-level
>   predicate, expressing a property of properties. Thus ‘God
>   exists’ does not have the same logical form as ‘Sirius
>   shines’, predicating a property of a particular object.
>   Rather, it is equivalent to ‘Godhood is instantiated’, asserting
>   that the property of being divine has at least one
>   instance, or that there is at least one thing possessing that
>   property.

We may notate the proposition 'Sirius shines' thus:
$ \exists s(Ss) $

However, I don't know how to notate the proposition 'the property of Godhood is instantiated'. I presume it involves second order logic.

How do logicians notate a proposition that posits the instantiation of a property?

Comment: Actually, given that "Sirius" is a proper name, I think it'd be more adequate to simply write $Ss$, with $s$ a constant denoting Sirius. As for the "the property of Godhood is instantiated", what's wrong with $\exists x Gx$, where $G$ is a predicate variable whose intended interpretation is "Godhood"?

Comment: @Nagase I thought about $\exists x (Gx)$. However, it seems to express the proposition 'God exists'. The proposition 'something instantiates the property Godhood' entails that God exists, but I don't think that it is identical to the proposition 'God exists'; although, perhaps it is.

Comment: Actually, $\exists x Gx$ literally says that there is an $x$ such that $x$ satisfies $G$, which seems pretty much equivalent to $G$ is instantiated.

Comment: The analysis of Frege amounts to : $Philosopher(Socrates)$ is *true* because the *individual* $Socrates$ "fall under" (i.e. satisfy) the *concept* $Philosopher(x)$, i.e. the individual $Socrates$ has the property : $Philosophood$. This means that the property $Philosophood$ is *instantiated* (by the individual $Socrates$); i.e. $\exists x Philosopher(x)$ is *true*.

Answer (score 1):

From the SEP article on existence, it seems that Nagase and Mauro ALLEGRANZA are correct.

> To say that foxes exist is to say that there are some things that are foxes; that is, the property of being a fox is instantiated. This is reflected in the standard regimentation of the sentences ‘Foxes exist’ and ‘There are foxes’ in first-order quantificational logic as ∃xFx, where Fx is the translation for the predicate ‘is a fox’.